# How to replace cell formula with its own value via UDF?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

**Problem Description**

I have a custom formula that I wrote, but it takes a while to calculate the answer, and since Excel updates function values (When you activate the workbook, or re-open the workbook, etc.), I can't have it re-running the function.

I tried calling a Sub process to copy the cell and paste values ([Replace a formula with its result](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/replace-a-formula-with-its-result-HP010066258.aspx)), but it returns `=#VALUE!`. Probably something to do with circular references...

**Question**

Is there a way to overwrite the formula in a cell with its value from within a user defined formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to overwrite any cell from within a UDF, it can only return a value.

You can use the Worksheet_Change function to get around this...

In Sheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Intersect(Range("A1"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    'do nothing - not worried about anything not in A1
Else
    Range("A1").Value = Range("A1").Value
End If
End Sub
```

Whatever formula you type into A1, on the sheet you put this code into, will be converted into the value, and the formula removed.

Comment: Thanks! I guess that will have to do. I was hoping to put the UDF in an excel addon (.xlam) so that it would be available on all worksheets, but I guess that's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

1. Select Cell
2. Right-click > Copy (Or [CTRL]+[c])
3. Right-click > Paste Special > Paste Values

This should replace the formula with the resulting number/value.

Comment: Thanks, but I was wanting to do that from within the UDF (please read my question more carefully).