# How to automatically replace Excel formula with value when date/time condition is met

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I need to record results of a constantly changing cell based on external criteria.

Cell `B3`'s value is changing, and I need to record the value of `B3` at specific points in time. Cell `D2` contains the date (`9/12/14`) and cell `D3` contains the real time (`7:30:58`). I have a table set up with specific times and dates in columns `I` (date) and `J` (time). I need to record the result of `B3` when the date/time meet the criteria in the table.

After looking into a way to do this, I realize that I will need to use VBA; however, I am very new to VBA. My initial thoughts were to have a simple `IF` function in H2 like

```
=IF($D$2&$D$3=I2&J2,"$B$3","")
```

However, once the time changes the criteria is no longer met and the result is gone, and I need to save the result. I also need the solution to apply to the next date and time located in I3 & J3, as well as I4 & J4, and so on.

Any help on a VBA solution would be very appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to replace cell formula with its own value via UDF?](http://superuser.com/questions/520595/how-to-replace-cell-formula-with-its-own-value-via-udf)

Comment: @Excellll: The referenced question has some answers that require manual invocation. How can Kurt get that functionality to be triggered by a time? Does Excel/VBA have something comparable to `at`, `cron`, and/or the Windows Task scheduler, so he can say “execute this code at 7:30:58”?

Comment: @G-Man okay, I see now. I've revised the title and retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following example matches what you requested. I created a VB subroutine to put a random value in B3, to simulate the changing value in your situation. The VB code also checks the current date and time against values in a list, and if they match, it records the random value in a cell next to the matching date and time. Not shown in the pictures below is the technique I used to put date-only and time-only values in D2 and D3 so that the comparisons work out. For the date, I used this:

```
=datevalue(month(now()) & "/" & day(now()) & "/" year(now()))
```

And for the time value:

```
=time(hour(now()),minute(now()),second(now()))
```

[image: capturing values when specific date and time are matched]
[image: code to run every second]
[image: launch code when wookbook opens]

Comment: Could you please post your code as text? Screen captures are inconvenient for people wanting to use or adapt this code.

Comment: Excellll - it's all I had at the moment due to Excel crashing; prioritized helping Kurt over getting everything perfect. Please feel free to edit the answer to include the code.